# How simple it can be?

Tags: axioms, incompleteness

My dream axiom system is only the integers with the usual addition axioms (commutative, associative), and with induction. a) does it have a name, b) can I show define ab, and show ab=ba in this system?, c) is Gödel valid for this system?

Comment: Have you considered Peano's construction of the integers?

Comment: [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) is decidable.

Answer (score 3):

The natural context for looking at addition of natural numbers *alone* is [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), $Pres$. The language consists only of the binary function symbol "$+$" and constant symbols "$0$" and "$1$" together with the usual logical symbols, including "$=$." The axioms consist of some basic facts about addition, and the induction scheme for all formulas in the language.

*(Note that in fact the constant symbols are redundant, since they can be defined using $+$ alone: $0$ is the unique $x$ such that for all $y$, $x+y=y$, and $1$ is the unique $x$ such that for all $y$, either $y=0$ or there is some $z$ such that $x+z=y$.)*

The theory $Pres$ is meant to describe the structure $\mathcal{N}_+=(\mathbb{N}; +, 0, 1)$, in the same way that the intended model of PA is $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}; +,\times, 0, 1)$. There is a fundamental difference, however: it turns out that $Pres$ *completely* describes $\mathcal{N}_+$, in the sense that every sentence true in $\mathcal{N}_+$ is provable from $Pres$. Note that this immediately implies that $Pres$ is a complete theory (since if $\varphi$ is any sentence, either $\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal{N}_+$ or $\neg\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal{N}_+$). In particular, Godel's incompleteness theorem does not apply to it.

Note that by the compactness theorem, $Pres$ does **not** completely describe $\mathcal{N}_+$ up to isomorphism - there will be models of $Pres$ which aren't isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}_+$, for example any uncountable model of $Pres$.

Now, multiplication can be "recursively defined" using addition in an obvious way (more on this below). However, this does **not** constitute an actual definition in the sense of first-order logic: to put this precisely, the function $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}: (x, y)\mapsto x\cdot y$ is not definable in the structure $\mathcal{N}_+$. There is a fundamental difference between the idea of a *recursive* definition and a *first-order* definition, and in general they can't be conflated.

*As an aside, and very broadly speaking, the key property of a "strong enough" theory of arithmetic as far as Godel is concerned is that it **can** "first-orderize" a large class of recursive definitions in an appropriate way. This largely comes down to the ability to treat finite sequences appropriately (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441345/what-is-magic-about-the-combination-of-addition-and-multiplication-in-formal-a?noredirect=1&lq=1)): once we have multiplication, we can talk about finite sequences via [Godel's $\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function) (and it's even easier if we work in a context with exponentiation directly built in) but in Presburger arithmetic [we don't even have a pairing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192305/pairing-in-presburger-arithmetic).*

---

Now let's say a bit about the "recursive definition" of multiplication in $Pres$. There are a few ways to approach this. In my opinion, the most natural one is the following: we write a sentence $\varphi$ in the expanded language $\{+, 0,1, *\}$ which is intended to say that "$*$" is just multiplication. One obvious candidate formula is the universal closure of the conjunction of the following formulas:

- $x*0=0$,
- $x*y=y*x$,
- $x*(y+1)=(x*y)+x$.

(There are plenty of others.) Let's work with this choice of $\varphi$ for the moment.

Good news: there is *exactly one* expansion of $\mathcal{N}_+$ to our larger language which satisfies $\varphi$ - namely, we have to interpret $*$ as multiplication. This is an easy induction argument.

Bad news: this really only works with *this particular model*. In general, if $M\models Pres$, there is no reason to believe that there is *exactly one* expansion of $M$ to a model of $Pres\cup\{\varphi\}$ - maybe there are several, or none. That is, **$Pres$ isn't strong enough to guarantee that "multiplication," defined in the obvious recursive way, is a unique well-defined thing.**

---

Now a natural next question is:

> Starting with Presburger arithmetic, how much of the basic theory of multiplication can I add before I hit Godelian phenomena?

(Or conversely, starting with PA, how much can I take away and still have a theory to which Godel applies?)

I think a good place to get started, if you're interested, is to read about [self-verifying theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-verifying_theories); these are theories which can talk about multiplication to a certain extent, but which manage to prove their own consistency by virtue of not *quite* proving enough basic facts about multiplication for Godel to apply.

Specifically, they don't prove that multiplication is total! So this is really a big gap. To see the importance of totality, note that even the extremely weak theory [Robinson arithmetic, $Q$,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) is susceptible to Godel, and really the only thing $Q$ can do that Willard's theories can't is prove that multiplication is always defined. *Note that there isn't an axiom of $Q$ stating this; the totality of multiplication is an immediate consequence of having multiplication be denoted by a function symbol. In Willard's theories, we don't have a function symbol for multiplication but rather a relation symbol for the graph of multiplication.*